# Unable to see complete scraped web page in Google Apps Script logs

Tags: javascript, dynamic, google-apps-script, urlfetch

A few weeks ago I started learning Javascript and the Google Apps Script API, specifically in regard to spreadsheets. I have been trying to make a spreadsheet that fetches web pages and pulls stats about my friends for the game League of Legends. However, I have been running into a problem with the site I want to use, which is basically the only free LoL stats site that updates frequently. I'm not familiar at all with web development, but it seems when I try to access a page on lolking.net, for example http://www.lolking.net/summoner/na/60783 with Google's UrlFetchApp.fetch() it does not load the dynamic page. So instead of the final source, I get [this which doesn't help me](http://pastebin.com/TgRBKffP). Is there an easy way around this or would I simply have to use another website?

Comment: If you have found yourself here because you're having trouble scraping dynamic content with Google Apps Script, refer to [the canonical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788353/using-google-script-to-scrape-content-that-is-loaded-via-javascript/13790756#13790756) on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for thie info! Although it turns out I was mistaken. The UrlFetchApp was indeed returning the full source code, but I was using GAS's Logger to view the text. It seems the Logger has a length limit, so when I searched for the stats I wanted they weren't there simply because the source code got truncated. So, due to an oversight on my part, I never had a problem in the first place. For other people reading this question, in the end I have no idea how UrlFetchApp works with dynamic pages using clientside js (you'd probably want to talk to the poster below or post a new question).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting fhe raw html page with clientside js included. That wont work from any system not just gas. You need to debug that page js and find where it does an ajax call to get the data you want.
Then do the same from your gas. Might not work if the call is authenticated etc.