# How do you put ONLY one column in a row from a website into a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get ONLY one column in a row from a website into my google sheet. I attached some screenshots to further explain.

I would like to place the formula in row 8, column Q in my sheet. The first screenshot just shows what links me to the webpage based on what's in cell/column "A", but I still have to manually input what's in the webpage as it updates. I want the info from the webpage to automatically go into the google sheet.

I've tried

=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://nakedshortreport.com/company/",A8;"htable"),2,7)

=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://nakedshortreport.com/company/"&A8&"&in=","table",0),2,3)

=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://nakedshortreport.com/company/",A8, "table", 1), "SELECT row2, Col7")

But none of the formulas are working.

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEEtf.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuYK8.png)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://nakedshortreport.com/company/"&A8; "table"; 1); 
 "select Col7"); "offset 1 limit 1"; 0)
```

---

### update

site you are trying to import from uses JS and google sheets does not support importing JS elements...

[image]

Comment: when I use that formula it says #N/A in the cell and shows "imported content is empty" when I hover over the cell with my mouse.

Comment: @hank130 can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Content from this website is loaded dynamically via script, which makes it unreachable via formulas like [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en).

You can check that by [disabling JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/disable/) and refreshing the page: you'll get the following message:

> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

The content is not accessible via [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) either.

#### Related:

- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun)
- [Using Google Apps Script to scrape Dynamic Web Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13788353/using-google-apps-script-to-scrape-dynamic-web-pages)